# What is the easy way to import large database to mysql using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to import an database(sql file) which is about 120M is size, but in phpmyAdmin, it is not allowed to import more than 8 MB.

How to solve this?

Comment: If you have access to a console, using the command-line MySQL client to import is far faster.

Comment: Is your 120MB file a sql file?

Comment: it might be large compared to your 8 MB upload limit, but it's ridiculously small compared to really large databases ;) can't you use anything else but phpMyAdmin for this job? i.e. directly connect to your DB?

Comment: get best Ans [here](http://www.steptoinstall.com/import-big-database-sql-file-to-phpmyadmin-wamp-server.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC there is no limit in PHPMyAdmin nor is there in MySQL - the limit is on the POST size (webserver config) or the file upload size (php.ini). If you can't change either of these, then you'll need to upload the file by other means then ....

```
mysql -u username -p <mysql_export_file.sql
```

If you can't upload files / have no shell access / have no CLI version of the mysql client avaialable, then the next thing to try is to see whether you can connect remotely using the mysql CLI client:

```
mysql -u username -h www.example.com -p
```

If this connects OK, then exit and run it again piping in the exported file

```
mysql -u username -h www.example.com -p <mysql_export_file.sql
```

If that doesn't work then you'll need to either split the export file into multiple smaller chunks or write your own dataloader which trickles the data.

C.

Comment: additionally, he could stick with phpMyAdmin and 'simply' split the dump into easily digestible <8MB chunks.

Comment: @sfussenegger: how do you do that **'simply'**?

Comment: it's not that simple, hence the quotes ;) I just wanted to add this possibility as remark to your answer.

Comment: +1 the easiest way to import a large database using phpMyAdmin is not to use phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this in three ways in the past, here are the solutions in order of simplicity:

1) **Increase the upload limit.**  Ask your host to allow you to upload larger files to the server (specifically the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize variables), probably best that they do this in phpMyAdmin's .htaccess file.

2) **Upload via FTP.** PHPMyAdmin supports uploading of SQL files via FTP but your host needs to [configure the "UploadDir" setting](http://webdev1-etheory.inspire.net.nz/phpMyAdmin/Documentation.html#cfg_UploadDir).

3) **Use a different import process.** [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) is the best for this. The problem is that it does still refuses to import some files because of the number of SQL lines or other errors, plus you have to configure it for each site/database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct access to server, so successfully used [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php) istead. You upload it via FTP together with big SQL file. Then BigDump imports the local file on server, avoiding any HTTP/PHP upload limits.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the import is clean and doesn't have any duplicates then you could try the following which reduces the time considerably.

```
mysql> set autocommit=0; set unique_checks=0; set foreign_key_checks=0;
mysql> source /path/to/dump.sql
mysql> commit; set unique_checks=1; set foreign_key_checks=1;
```