# Importing a 12gb MySQL database into PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

SO guys, we had legacy website that has a 12GB MySQL database. We decided to port the legacy website to WordPress and need to import the database into PHPmyAdmin without breaking the database and to implement this in the shortest possible time (although time is not such a critical matter if this can be done painlessly but correctly). So would appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction and provide detailed instructions.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do not import a 12 GB file through phpmyadmin, it was not designed to handle this amount of data. It will time out long before the script would be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am aware of that and hence looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

***I dont know much*** but i can recommend to back up you're files befored doing any transfers. If you have a fast internet speed then you guys can try to download the SQL database as a compressed file and dump it into the wordpress new database. The database for mysql should be in your cpanel folder (since all cpanel folders/designs are different it would be best to look up "where to find the msql database on *hosting company name's* cpanel" and once you find it then you can transfer it whereever is possible)

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest and most correct way.

```
mysql -u username -p "dbname" < "path/to/bigdata.sql"
```

If you have FTP/SSH access, then this is the most probable way.

1. Upload your .sql via FTP
2. If you have access to CLI , just run the command above
3. Normally , this will be fast, but since its 12GB, it might take 30min-1hour depending on server resources.

You can also use other options like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972326/what-is-the-easy-way-to-import-large-database-to-mysql-using-phpmyadmin) .

I've already experienced importing 61GB before with just this one-liner.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I was not sure if I could use the command for such a large import. Will update tomorrow on how it went. Also please let me know if the command includes the "<" symbol?

Comment: @Tavy, yepp .. `<` is needed to tell mysql that you are doing an import.